# Representation-finite quivers over dual numbers

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Given a Dynkin quiver $Q$ and a field $K$.

> Question 1: For which such $Q$ are there only finitely many indecomposable representations over the dual numbers $K[x]/(x^2)$?

Note that those representations are exactly those of $KQ \otimes_K K[x]/(x^2)$.
This is for example true for $Q$ being of type $A_1, A_2$ or $A_3$.

> Question 2: For which combinations of $Q$ and $n$ is $KQ \otimes_K K[x]/(x^n)$ representation-finite?

I think question two has an easy answer for $n \geq 3$, namely only when $Q$ is of type $A_1$ for arbitrary $n$ or $A_2$ for $n=3$, but is there an elementary argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this result in [Geiss, Leclerc, Schröer: Quivers with relations for symmetrizable Cartan matrices I: Foundations] as Proposition 13.1. They consider a more general class of algebras. The class of algebras you are considering is obtained by setting their parameters $(c_1,\dots,c_m)$ to all the same number, which you call $n$.

Translating to your setup, their result reads:

> The algebra $KQ\otimes_K K[x]/(x^n)$ for $Q$ a Dynkin quiver is
>   representation-finite if and only if you are in one of the following
>   cases:
>
> 1. $n=1$ and $Q$ arbitrary, in which case you just recover $KQ$.
> 2. $Q=A_1$, the quiver with only one vertex, in this case $n$ is arbitrary.
> 3. $Q=A_2$ and $n=2$ or $n=3$.
> 4. $Q=A_3$ and $n=2$.

The proof they give (unfortunately) uses the Bongartz-Gabriel and the Happel-Vossieck list. The question for a more elementary argument thus remains open. For this one should try to construct an infinite family of modules.